# On sum of amplitudes in Wave Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, superposition

Consider Schroedinger equation, which I write in the form $$ (\mathscr{L}+V)\psi=0$$where $\mathscr{L}$ is the kinetic and time-derivative operator. Now, imagine I have two point sources 1,2 with potential $V_i(r)=f_i(r) \delta (r-r_i)$. Let $\psi_1$  (resp $\psi_2$) be the solution when I switch on only source 1 (resp 2). It is clear that when both sources are switched on then potential $V=V_1+V_2$. However, unlike the sum of amplitudes, $\psi\neq \psi_1+\psi_2$ , instead it is $$\psi=\psi_1+\psi_2-\frac{1}{\mathscr{L}+V}(V_1\psi_2+V_2\psi_1)$$ Consequently, every other quantities that can be derived from $\psi$ won't respect the usual linearity. I could use similar setup in double-slit experiment , where $V_i$ is infinite except at the location of slit $i$ (The total potential $V$ is infinite except at location of slits 1 and 2).
The argument above equally applies for classical theory like Electro-magnetism (as shown [here](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.85.012101)).

It seems from above argument that if EM field (or wavefunction) from multiple sources are given, I cannot always vectorially add them to get the overall field strength at a point. So when should the vector sum of field strength/ sum of amplitudes be valid?

Comment: Your formalism is unclear, but it looks like $V_i$ is defined to project out any and all solutions except $\psi_i$, i.e. it includes, unstated, some type of a projector to *just*  $\psi_i$, in which case the last term of your 2nd displayed equation vanishes by definition. Can you be more precise in your question?

Comment: @CosmasZachos By projector, do you mean writing $V_1\to V_1\otimes \mathbb{1}$ and $V_2\to \mathbb{1}\otimes V_2$ so that the cross-terms cancel out?

Comment: I mean they ensure, e.g., $V_1 \psi_2$ is zero, by construction.

Comment: I am simply adding two potentials here. I don't know why I should consider something like a composite hilbert space in this case. I'll think about this . Moreover, the article I have linked above comments a similar idea for Electro-magnetic waves so I don't see a way to counter that argument

Comment: It's not clear how the infinities of each V do not overwhelm/plug the delta of the other... I strongly disagree your quoted reference is relevant here.

Comment: I agree that delta potentials can be overwhelming in the last term of the 2nd equation, but it was only an example. We can consider any finite well behaved potentials for $V_i$, $V$. Also, page 4 and 5 in the above article talks about the case for EM waves. The reason I linked this article is that this deviation has been measured experimentally and its ~0 in Fraunhofer regime. There are other articles on this measurement. What bothers me is that vector sum of fields/ amplitudes in this linearized regime should have been an "exact" rule and not approximate - which is not according to experiment

Comment: "The authors could not think of a general physical situation that would result in Eq. (11)." But you believe you did!?

Comment: What I understood was that the authors couldn't find a general scenario where the cross terms V1ψ2 etc should vanish. This is what I have asked above. And you have suggested to think V's and ψ's in terms of projector which leads to vanishing of these extra terms. However, such deviation has also been obtained from [path integral approach](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00677704) , so I don't know why the projection argument should work here

Comment: This new ref, Fig 2 settles the issue. The loop involved cannot be considered as part of $\psi_1$, *as originally defined*, with a plugged second slit: that plug is the projection. The authors of your first reference use “general” for “generic”. Not an implicit failure of a general proof! There is no paradox here. Once you try to appreciate the definition of your sum potential, the “paradox” collapses….

Comment: Oh I see it now! Thank you so much for your time!